# native image creation fails after upgrading graalvm version from 22.1.0 to 22.3.2

Tags: java, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm compiling my micronaut application into a native image using the command `native-image -cp build/libs/*-all.jar`, which is executed within a docker image. I also supply a `native-image.properties` file that looks like below:

```
Args = -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=build/graal/resource-config.json,build/native/generated/generateResourcesConfigFile/resource-config.json \
       -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=build/graal/reflect-config.json,build/resources/main/graal/reflect-config.json \
       -H:JNIConfigurationFiles=build/graal/jni-config.json \
       -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=build/graal/proxy-config.json \
       -H:PredefinedClassesConfigurationFiles=build/graal/predefined-classes-config.json \
       -H:Name=micronautgraalapp \
       --no-fallback \
       --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime \
       --initialize-at-build-time=sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl \
       --install-exit-handlers \
       -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https \
       -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
       -H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC \
       -J-Xmx3072m \
       -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED \
       -H:Class=io.github.devatherock.ldapsearch.Application
```

I use the shortcut command `make fast-build docker-build` which runs the tests first, to generate the reflection config, and then builds the native image within docker. This works fine and creates the native image successfully with graalvm version `22.1.0`. The working version of the application can be found [here](https://github.com/devatherock/ldap-search-api). After upgrading graalvm version to `22.3.2`, the native image creation fails midway with the below exception:

```
#10 84.42 Error: Unsupported features in 4 methods
#10 84.42 Detailed message:
#10 84.42 Error: Detected a ZipFile object in the image heap. A ZipFile object contains pointers to unmanaged C memory and file descriptors, and these resources are no longer available at image runtime.  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.jar.JarFile. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>. Or you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from your main entry point.
#10 84.42 Trace: Object was reached by
#10 84.42   reading field jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferences$JarModuleReader.jf of constant 
#10 84.42     jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferences$JarModuleReader@7205edd8: jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferences$JarModuleReader@7205edd8
#10 84.42   reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of constant 
#10 84.42     java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@4d58ca3f: [module org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder, location=file:///usr/lib64/graalvm/graa...
#10 84.42   indexing into array java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@639968a3: [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;@639968a3
#10 84.42   reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of constant 
#10 84.42     java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@60bb74c6: {[module jdk.internal.ed, location=jrt:/jdk.internal.ed]=jdk.internal.module.Sys...
#10 84.42   reading field jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.moduleToReader of constant 
#10 84.42     jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cfb4a64: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cfb4a64
#10 84.42   reading static field java.lang.ClassLoader.scl
```

Setting both `java.util.jar.JarFile` and `java.util.zip.ZipFile` classes to initialize at runtime using `--initialize-at-run-time` also did not help - causes a different error saying that the class has already been initialized. The failing version of the code is present in a [different branch](https://github.com/devatherock/ldap-search-api/compare/graal-22.3.2?expand=1)